# Make zsh print absolute line number on error not function relative line number

Tags: zsh

When zsh has an error it prints out the line number relative to the function start. Is there a way to force it to print the absolute line number within the file instead?

Comment: AFIK, no. Note that this information does not necessarily make sense. The function could be defined in your interactive zsh, or as a result of some `eval`.

Comment: Might be able to use `${(%):-%I}`, but I'm not sure how I'd set it up. In a trap maybe...

Comment: `%I` is used in prompt expansion.....

Comment: I just learned the `%` flag allows you to use prompt expansions in parameter expansions

Comment: Good point! Never thought about this. From the zsh-man-page, I see that %i and %I are intended for use with the PS4 variable. Perhaps this information is not kept if tracing is off. For curiosity, you could turn on tracing (with `set -x`), and THEN attempt your expansion trick.

Comment: FYI: I just tried a `echo ${(%):-%I}`, and it indeed prints the current line of the script (i.e. the line of the _echo_ command); trace is not needed. I think this is useful. SInce you found out about this, perhaps you could post it as an answer? It is OK to answer your own question.

Comment: Ah, but I see that you want to trick zsh to use this automatically, if an error occurs. I don't think that this can be done. Even in a trap, you have foremost the line number inside the trap function.

Comment: Just a vague idea: If you do a `trap 'myhandler ${(%):-%I}' ZERR` (single quotes are crucial), perhaps your function `myhandler` will be called with the correct line number. Don't have the time to test it....

Comment: Did some experiments without much luck. `%I` inside a trap only gives the fn-relative number as you said and `trap handle ERR` with a trap i the handle fn just gives the absolute line of the handle function. I did find [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453144/functions-calling-context-in-zsh-equivalent-of-bash-caller) which I may try when I have more energy...

Comment: Maybe you could edit your question and post the exact `trap` statements you tried....